How can I use JSON Schema to require a specific property if and only if the value of another property matches a constant?
I am already aware of how to conditionally require the presence of a property based on the value of another property. What I am looking for is the reverse as well.
In my case, I have a property called "type" that can have multiple values. If the type is equal to the constant "enum", then I also require a property named "enum" to be present. But what I also want is that if the "enum" property is present but "value" is not equal to the constant "enum", I want it to fail validation.
Here is what I have currently:
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.org/schemas/field",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "group": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "title": {
      "$ref": "i18n.schema.json"
    },
    "description": {
      "$ref": "i18n.schema.json"
    },
    "type": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "boolean",
        "string",
        "strings",
        "path",
        "enum",
        "map",
        "integer",
        "password"
      ]
    },
    "default": {
      "$ref": "value.schema.json"
    },
    "required": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "dependency.schema.json"
      }
    },
    "enum": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "map": {
      "$ref": "map.schema.json"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "name",
    "title",
    "type"
  ],
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "const": "enum"
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "required": [
          "enum"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "const": "map"
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "required": [
          "map"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "additionalProperties": false
}

Edit:
Here is an example of a valid JSON:
{
    "type": "enum",
    "enum": "foo"
}

Here are some invalid ones:
The property 'enum' is present, but type is not equal to "enum":
{
    "type": "string",
    "enum": "foo"
}

The property type contains the constant value "enum", but the property enum is not present.
{
    "type": "enum"
}


I think what you're asking is the following:
if type: enum, then enum: something but not enum: enum
"allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "const": "enum"
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "required": [
          "enum"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "enum": {
            "not": {
              "const": "enum"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]


Side note, the reason we use allOf rather than anyOf with the conditional statements is because anyOf will break after the first match, whereas allOf must validate all schemas before returning a validation result.

EDIT after comment:
the conditional statement I wrote, covers that use case.  The only thing you don't need is the properties schema in the then clause for the first conditional.  Otherwise, I didn't account for enum: <string> existence without the type:<string> keyword definition. In that case, you can write another conditional and flip the evaluation.
"allOf": [
  {
    "if": {
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "const": "enum"
        }
      }
    },
    "then": {
      "required": [
        "enum"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "if": {
      "properties": {
        "enum": true
      }
    },
    "then": {
      "required": [
        "type"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "const": "enum"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


Based on your wording, I don't think that's what I mean. What I mean is that if the property "type": "enum" is present, then there must also be a 2nd property named enum of type "string", which contains the unique name of a custom enum type. And conversely, if the property enum exists (with any string value), then the value of type must be equal to the string "enum".
I've updated the question with an example.
